# Which is the correct tense to be used in this sentence?

Tags: tense, exam-questions

Could you tell me which the correct answer is and why, please?

> "What is this strange smell?"  "The food _________"
>   a) has burnt
>   b) burnt
>   c) was burning
>   d) had burnt

Comment: When asking a question like this one, the community would like to know: Have you at least narrowed it down to two answers? Is there a reason this particular question is vexing you? For example, do they all look right to you? Do none of them look write to you? The more details you provide, the easier it is for us to explain and give a more helpful answer. You may want to edit this question and provide some more details.

Answer (score 1):

The correct tense would be 'The food has burnt'.

'The food burnt', indicates that at some stage in the past the food burnt, but that has no connection to the current time.

'The food has burnt', indicates that at some time in the past the food burnt, and continues to have a current effect. In this case the continuing effect is the strange smell that continues to be in the air. This phrase can also be used if the food is still burning, although it would be more common to say, 'The food is burning'.

'The food was burning' and 'The food had burnt' is more likely to be a response to the question, 'What was that strange smell'.

---

My answer above was based on the assumption that two people are in the same location when one asks the question, 'What is that strange smell?'

I should also have thought about the possibility that the first person enters a house, or a room, a few minutes after the food burnt and asks the  question 'What is that strange smell?' In this case, because a period of time had elapsed between the cause (the food burning) and the result (the lingering smell) the second person could have responded, 'The food burnt'.

There is insufficient context in your question to determine which of these scenarios is correct. In the absence of such context, I still lean towards my first answer as it requires less supposition.

Comment: But the connection is made explicit by saying that the smell is due to the burning that occurred in the past. Swan gives an example *Why are you crying?* ~ *Granny hit me.* (not *Granny has hit me.*). What's the difference between that example and the one the asker is asking about?

Comment: The "Granny hit me" example is an emotional outburst. It shows surprise or indignation, for example. You can check it at www.grammar-quizzes.com.

Comment: @userr2684291 I have no problem with anyone pointing out any errors that I may have made. I have made errors in the past, and will probably do so in the future.  I still stand by my answer, although I have amended my answer to provide more context. The grammar-quizzes.com reference that anouk mentioned is at https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/past2.html.

Comment: @James Oh, I don't think you made any mistakes (I've actually upvoted your answer). I don't believe you can, really, because these situations and sentences must be quite simple and ordinary, and I don't imagine you'd have to think twice about which tense you'd use. I guess I merely wanted to see why the explanation you provided doesn't apply to my example, and how you'd reason about it. That's all.

Comment: @anouk I don't think that's a *necessary* angle to approach this stuff from ("emotional outburst"). I guess it *works*, but just like the recency explanation of the present perfect, it doesn't quite pin it down.

Comment: @ Raaffaa  First, let me say that your written English is excellent. I think that a strong argument could be made that either (a) or (b) is an acceptable answer. Unfortunately, with multiple-choice questions, this is not as unusual an event as you might like to believe. It can be difficult writing a dozen or so questions and then, for each question, providing only one correct answer plus 3 or 4 other answers which, superficially at least, look like they might be correct. I still feel that 'has burnt' is the correct answer, but I don't think I would say that 'burnt' is absolutely wrong.